# Map entity to view and table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Consider the model below. I have an `Order` class and an `OrderLine` class. The `Order.TotalAmount` is calculated through a view which performs an `OUTER APPLY` across all the `Order.OrderLines`.

```
[Table("SelectOrder")]
public class Order
{
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

[Table("SelectOrderLine")]
public class OrderLine
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

I have decorated my classes with the `TableAttribute` to enable Entity Framework Core to get the data from the views to the entity. The `TableAttribute` actually points to the view instead.

Now I would like to perform inserts, updates and deletes. This poses a problem as it's not possible to use a view with an `OUTER APPLY` for these changes. I've tried using query types for this but you cannot define an entity as both a query type and an entity type. Doing so results in an error for me. So adding a `TableAttribute` with the actual table e.g. `Order` in combination with `modelBuilder.Query<Order>().ToView("SelectOrder");` does not work.

I could create a separate class SelectOrder which is mapped to the view and map my Order entity to the table. Or I could build a custom attribute and perform some custom SQL generation by overriding the `SqlServerQuerySqlGenerator`.

But before I go down these roads... Is it really not possible to map an entity to both a view for selects and a table for inserts, updates and deletes?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but you could add a calculated OrderTotal attribute to the Order table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET 5 Preview version was released it's possible to support a separation of query and update the mapping

ref. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A5.0.0-preview2+is%3Aclosed+label%3Atype-enhancement+is%3Aclosed